# How to create a circuit for this signal? Transistor?

Tags: transistors, esp32

today I measured a signal with my oszilloscope. Its a pressed button of my robotic vacuum cleaner. The strange thing for me is, that in idle mode (button not pressed) the signal level is at 3.3 volts. But if I press the button the voltage goes up to 4.5 volts and drops than to 800 mV. This repeats until I release the button.

Its a SPST button like you find on a keypad.

The button starts the robot. I don't want to press it every time manually, I want to "press" the button remote via the GPIOs of my ESP.

I measured the voltage on the mainboard. There is a pin header where the button is connected directly to the mainboard.

What I want to do is now, I want to trigger the button via the GPIO of my ESP32. Do you have clue what kind of transistor-circuit I need? I need to raise the current somehow to 4.5 volts...

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but FYI I would not start with the question you have. If the signal line idles at 3.3 V, that is likely the supply or I/O voltage (Vdd/Vio) for the IC receiving that signal. Therefore it would be unusual for it to receive a higher voltage on that pin, despite what you measured. Instead of accepting those voltages at face value, I would be reverse-engineering the circuitry around that push button and the signal it supplies. I would not be surprised if a much simpler solution is possible, than duplicating that strange signal from the scope trace. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us much about the nature of the button (number of poles, number of throws), but if a Single Pole, Double Throw (SPDT) button is being used, here's one way you could get that effect.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbMt57.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But it sounds like you are trying to *replace* that effective circuit with an equivalent implementation that *listens* to the button state and *outputs* either 3.3V or a 250Hz 0-4.5V square wave.

One way to get that effect would be to use an 2-to-1 analog multiplexer, plugin 3.3V into one of its inputs, and plug in the output of a circuit that generates the square 0-4.5V square wave constantly, then use your ESP32 to set the control bits to the analog multiplexer to output the correct input channel based on the state of the button, which you are also tracking with the ESP32.

Assuming you have a 4.5V source voltage, the following circuit will convert a 0-3.3V square wave into a 0-4.5V square wave.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdYzEx.png)</sup>

Obviously, this requires you to decouple the button from the current circuit and treat it as a "dumb" input to your microcontroller, then disconnect the node which generates the output you measured with your scope and instead connect that node to the output of the analog multiplexer.

Comment: Just for clarification: when I use a multiplexer (e.g. ADG704,  switches one of four inputs to a common output) isn't it better to connect the keypad button (3.3 volts idle) to one of the inputs of the multiplexer and the other input to the square wave signal? Then I can simply switch between the connected button and my square wave when I want to simulate a pressed button and do not need to read the button via the µC.

Comment: yes there are many ways to approach it